# React: changing icon on mouseEnter using state. Icon stuck on "hover" state if I move the mouse too fast

Tags: reactjs, hover, icons, onmousemove

I have a component with an unchecked checkbox icon. When hovering over the icon, I am displaying a checked version of the icon. I am using state to set the isHovered state to true when the mouse enters the div that contains the icon and to false when the mouse leaves the div. I do a conditional rendering in the div, using an unchecked icon if the isHovered state is false and a checked icon if isHovered is true.

My component is used multiple times in a row in my app and my issue is that if I move my mouse fast over the icons, some of them get stuck in the isHovered state true even if the mouse is not over them anymore.

Any suggestions to fix this behavior ?

Here is my code:

```
const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  const onMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };
  const onMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  return (

        <div
          onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
          onClick={handleArchive}
          style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", cursor: "pointer" }}
        >
          {isHovered ? (
            <CheckCircleIcon
              style={{ color: "grey", fontSize: 20, marginRight: 10 }}
            />
          ) : (
            <RadioButtonUncheckedIcon
              style={{ color: "grey", fontSize: 20, marginRight: 10 }}
            />
          )}
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you using the same state across each checkbox icon/radio button?

Comment: I'm mapping through an array to generate multiple copies of my component. Each component is managing its own state

Comment: Hmmm everything seems fine then. I would try console logging when mouse enters and leave into each element to see how those functions are called but it seems fine anyway

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
 
  return (

        <div
          onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(!isHovered)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(!isHovered)}
          onClick={handleArchive}
          style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", cursor: "pointer" }}
        >
          {isHovered ? (
            <CheckCircleIcon
              style={{ color: "grey", fontSize: 20, marginRight: 10 }}
            />
          ) : (
            <RadioButtonUncheckedIcon
              style={{ color: "grey", fontSize: 20, marginRight: 10 }}
            />
          )}
        </div>
```

Solution 2: A simple css-only solution

Comment: I think that's not a good approach since you dont wan't to switch the state of `isHovered`, when you leave the `div`, you want it to be `false` and vice-versa. Also it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I did try to toggle instead of setting to false but the behavior was even worse

Comment: You can use onMouseOver & onMouseOut instead onMouseEnter & onMouseLeave.